# Two PostGis layers conflict in QGIS (cann't display at the same time)

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, shapefile, qgis

i added layers from PostGis. One layer (traffic history) is downloaded from the state DOT website (originally a shape file); the others are from Tiger road network data (also shapefiles). These two types of layers can't be displayed at the same time.  When I imported the traffic history one first, it can display this one but later when I add other layers, they don't show up; vice versa. 
The traffic history one is for the whole state; the road network one is only for one county. could this be a problem?

this is the traffic history layer (whole state):
[image]

this is the road network layer (one county):
[image]

Comment: I would like to provide other information of the two layers. I just don't know what might cause this right now.

Comment: The two datasource have different coordinate systems. Add the output of this command for both shp files: `ogrinfo -al -so YOUR_DATA.shp`. Please add the command output in the question's body and not as comment

Comment: On which platform are you working on? How to install ogr on windows: http://www.northrivergeographic.com/gdal-installation-windows